# Edit Windows 11 theme's background/text colours other than "Contrast themes"?

Tags: themes, windows-11, color-theme

I think the dark theme of Windows 11 lacks contrast for me. For example, the background of is not dark enough, and the text colour is not white enough. But theme customisation does not seem to allow me to edit the background/text colour. Can I create a custom theme with custom background/text colours?

In Personalisation > Themes, there is something called "Contrast themes" which allows me to set completely black background, but it seems that this feature is some sort of special feature for the people with eyesight problems. If I set a contrast theme, I cannot change the accent colour, I do not want those; I just want to change the background/text colours.

[image]

Comment: Are the registry colors at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors` useful here, and especially `Window` and `WindowText`. See [article](https://winaero.com/change-window-text-color-in-windows-10/)?

Comment: @harrymc Those are old Win32 values. They probably do not work with new so-called UWP apps like the Calculator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the File Explorer, navigate to "C:\Users\ [your user name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes".  Right click the theme you want to change and choose 'Open With'.  Choose to open the theme with WordPad (or your text editor of choice).  Scroll down and you will see all of the different color settings in RGB hexadecimal format.  Alter them from there.

In order to get the changes to take effect, I had to go back into Settings>Personalization>Themes, select a different theme, wait for it to take effect, then select my theme again.

Comment: Well, those values `[Control Panel\Colors] Section` does not seem to apply to UWP apps, which now even Notepad is, and seeing the file and [this reference page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/themesfileformat-overview#control-panelcolors-section) I think the colours of UWP are loaded from aero.msstyles which is binary. The only colour settings I can change is `ColorizationColor` which is probably the accent colour. I guess this means that there is no easy way to achieve what I want without hacking Window binary, so I think I will give up.